# question 1.3.3 in section 1.3 of serge lang's complex analysis book

Tags: complex-analysis

I am going through serge lange's book ( albeit slowly ) and I don't understand one of the
exercises and I even have the answer because I have the solution book by Rami Sharkarchi.

I will state the question and then skip a few lines for those who want to try to answer it without seeing the answer. My problem is that, even with the answer, I don't understand it.

Question: Let $f(z) = e^{2\pi i z}$.  Describe the image under f of the set shaded in Figure 7. I can't draw figure 7,  but it consists of the points $x + i y$ with $-1/2 <= x <= 1/2$
and $ y >= B$. So, the set is essentially an rectangle with one side parallel to the x axis
and crossing the vertical axis at point B. The rectangle has a width of 1 and continues
up towards $y = \infty$.

I will skip some lines and then write the answer.

### --

### --

### --

### --

Answer: If $z = x + i y$, then $f(z) = e^{2 \pi i (x + iy)} = e^{- 2\pi y} e^{2 \pi x i} $.

But, $-1/2 <= x <= 1/2$ so $-\pi <= 2 \pi x <= \pi$. Also, $y >= B$ so $-2 \pi y <= -2\pi B$.

Those two statements make sense. It's the next two statements where I get lost.

To quote: "From the above expression, we see that the absolute value of $f(z)$ is $
e^{-2\pi y}$ and the argument of $f(z)$ is $2 \pi x i$. So, the image of the shaded region under $f$ is the closed disk of radius $e^{- 2\pi B} minus the origin. "

The only part of above that make sense to me is that the argument of $f(z)$ is $2 \pi x$.
I don't follow any of the rest of it. Thanks in advance to anyone who could explain what it is saying.

Answer (score 1):

Since $e^{2 \pi x i}$ has absolute value of 1 then the absolute value of $f(z)$ is just $e^{-2 \pi y}$ (It is the real part of f if we think of $f(z)$ as $re^{\theta i}$) and since $y \geq B$ then the absolute value of $f(z)$ ranges from $(0,e^{-2 \pi B}]$ (It is open at zero because y approaches infinity)

Comment: thank you very much. I will read carefully ( a few times )  and then probably put a check.

Comment: I understand now. I also edited the question because I had left out the $i$ in the $e{2 \pi x i}$.

Comment: Glad I could help you!